# How to generate regular CSS file from SASS?

Tags: css, sass, webpack

Normally I use

```
{ test: /\.sass$/, loader: 'style!css!sass?indentedSyntax' }
```

and then in `main.js`

```
require('./styles.sass')
```

But it applies style using javascript when `main.js` is loaded. The problem is that my app us isomorphic and returns some html initially. Because I load `main.js` just before `</body>` tag, then styles are applied to document a bit too late (user sees not-styled HTML for a moment).

Therefore I would like to generate regular css file from `styles.sass` and then simply include id in `<head></head>` to make sure it is loaded initially. How I can generate regular css file?

I tried:

```
entry: {
  styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/styles.sass')
}
```

but it generates `styles.js` instead of `.css` file. Moreover if I include `styles.js` in a head then I get following error in console from `styles.js`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

Put this in your `loaders:`

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css!sass") }
```

...and in your `plugins:`

```
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
]
```

Adapted from...

http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle

Answer (score 0):

When I use Sass in my projects, I in most cases use the same file structure. At least when it comes to the css-folder.

```
├── index.html
├── /css 
│   ├── style.css
│   ├── /sass
│   ├───── style.scss
│   ├───── ...
```

In the `public` folder where I tend to put my js, css and images folder, I always make a batch file. Something like this:

```
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
sudo sass --watch css/sass:css
```

This works for all my projects. I just run it and minimize the window. This looks for changes and converts Sass to regular css to the `style.css`file. Then in my `index.html` I just include `css/style.css`.

Hope this helps you

Comment: But I want it to be handled by webpack actually.